# tracert: first hop dependent of target

Tags: traceroute

I was checking my Internet connection at home and run the following commands. I was surprised by the response because the first hop sounds to be different depending on the host that I try to reach.

When I try to contact github.com (and many hosts):

```
> tracert github.com

Tracing route to github.com [140.82.121.4]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     4 ms     3 ms     3 ms  mymodem [192.168.1.1]
  2     9 ms     7 ms     7 ms  10.24.145.50
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4    76 ms    11 ms    62 ms  ae-74-100.ibrstr6.isp.proximus.be [91.183.242.132]
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7    28 ms    23 ms    22 ms  ae1.cs1.cdg12.fr.eth.zayo.com [64.125.29.86]
  8    24 ms    21 ms    20 ms  ae0.cs1.cdg11.fr.eth.zayo.com [64.125.29.85]
```

when I try to contact google.com:

```
>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [2a00:1450:400e:80e::200e]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    32 ms    13 ms     9 ms  host.dynamic.voo.be [2a02:2788:1a8:6b1:10:18ff:febe:d1e3]
  2    25 ms    21 ms    20 ms  host.dynamic.voo.be [2a02:2788:1a0:1::1]
  3    19 ms    17 ms    15 ms  host.dynamic.voo.be [2a02:2788:1a0:2::1]
  4    40 ms    30 ms    38 ms  2a02:2788:ffff:e::1
  5    40 ms    70 ms    53 ms  2001:7f8:13::a501:5169:1
```

when I try to contact microsoft.com

```
>tracert learn.microsoft.com

Tracing route to e13636.dscb.akamaiedge.net [2a02:a000:1:39e::3544]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  2a02:a03f:c47f:b300:5a2f:f7ff:fef8:c66b
  2     *        *
```

Also for background:

```
ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:2788:1a8:6b1:275d:5efa:4031:bf19
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:a03f:c47f:b300:2ad0:aa14:1bf5:862e
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:2788:1a8:6b1:fdd0:622b:e3d5:eafa
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:a03f:c47f:b300:fdd0:622b:e3d5:eafa
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c8a2:4a30:e86d:844f%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::10:18ff:febe:d1e3%9
                                       fe80::5a2f:f7ff:fef8:c66b%9
                                       192.168.1.1
```

My Internet provider is Proximus, VOO is another Internet provider available in the region but I'm not their customer. Proximus Default Gateway is by default 192.168.1.1 and VOO's default Gateway is by default 192.168.0.1

Naively, I was expecting to always get [192.168.1.1] as the first hop. Could anyone explain how it's possible to have different first hops?

Is there anything that I could do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I have noticed that your computer uses an IPv4 and two different IPv6 subnets? As does your router. However, home networking, consumer-grade hardware and networks not under your control are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably noticed, the first trace uses IPv4, but the 2nd and 3rd use IPv6.  Your provider appears to be using some sort of tunneling -- perhaps they don't natively support IPv6.

```
Is there anything that I could do to prevent this behavior?
```

I can't imagine why you'd want to, but you could disable the IPv6 stack on your computer.

Comment: Yep, I noticed but it doesn't explain why with IPv4, I'm going through a route starting to my modem then to Proximus and with IPv6 I'm directly on VOO. Sounds weird.

Comment: As I said in my answer, your ISP is apparently using some tunneling.  I can't comment why your ISP does that since speculation is off topic here, as are questions about networks you don't control.

Comment: Thx, I'll contact them to understand a bit what they are doing. In the meantime, I desactivated the IPv6 and the connection to websites using IPv6 such as microsoft and Google is now much more stable and faster